bitcoin core 27 initial sync blockchain errors
i was sent here from reddit
https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/1d5wgma/bitcoin_core_27_initial_sync_blockchain_errors/
i did some research and checked the debug.log, it had this error twice:
2024-06-01T20:22:08Z Fatal LevelDB error: Corruption: 18 missing files; e.g.: /run/media/ml/ssdfullnode/btc/datadir/blocks/index/000470.ldb

i never had a power outtage and always shut down everything correctly and typed "sync" in shell
then i tried -reindex and -reindex-chainstate
both times bitcoin-qt crashed without any message and debug.log showed me this error
2024-06-01T22:23:20Z Error: Out of memory. Terminating.

then i found a post by master jonasschnelli, who wrote using:
dbcache=20
maxconnections=3
par=2
maxmempool=50
yet bitcoin-qt still crashes with out of memory
i had no other applications open and checked my ram, it climbs to 9GB out of my 16GB then already crashes
everywhere it tells me 2gb should be enought to run btc core 27 :(
is there any solution to my stuck misery?

Does the file mentioned in the error message exist and have the expected permissions?

Are you sure Bitcoin Core is using the bitcoin.conf file you created? Can you include the first few dozen lines of debug.log? What operating system/filesystem is this one?

Hey, OP here,  @RedGrittyBrick yes everything had read/write acces and sry dunno if file rly existed, but i tried syncing the blockchain 4 times on linux and always failed at other blockheights when i had to close bitcoin core.

Hey, OP here,  @Pieter Wuille yes, the debug.log shows it used all the options i chose. i used Manjaro Arch linux fully updated and the 2tb ssd had ntfs fs, because i had to exchange files between windows and linux for work (which is why i have to close btc core once a day)  https://pastebin.com/vsDdNVcD

also UPDATE: i tested around a lot and linux seems to have serious issues with either 1 or a combination of these 3 things: - im using a ssd to usb3 adapter - ntfs fs  - many files in one single folder.   i had issues like pcmanfm filecount went to ininity when i inspected folder properties. and the estimated size of the folder went over the capacity of the ssd.  i also got problems mounting the ssd, so i had to chkdsk /f the ssd on windows.  after that i started the windows btc core software and voila everything seems fine, it got past the bootup screen and is now even syncing remaining blks
